# php wont post my html form

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="create.php">
Job #: <input type="text" name="jobnum">
<br>
Program: <input type="text" name="program"><br />
Ship Date: <input type="text" name="shipdate"><br />
Description: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="description"><br /><br />
Proto Verified By: <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
Additional Notes: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="notes"><br />
<input type="submit" name="value" value="submit" />
</form>
```

php:

```
$savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];
if ($savedata == 1){

$data = $_POST['jobnum']  . "\r\n";
$data .= $_POST['program']  . "\r\n";
$data .= $_POST['description']  . "\r\n";
$data .= $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
$data .= $_POST['notes']  . "\r\n";

$file = "YOURDATAFILE.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Your Form has been Submitted!";

}
```

I am not sure why my php will not post my form. My submit goes the the php page but it is completely blank. I am kind of new to code so I may need some detailed response...

Comment: Form has no `name` attribute.

Comment: Is the page blank? If so, you have errors and need to turn on error reporting to see them.

Comment: if the page is blank, write an else t if($savedata == 1) with an echo and look if it echoes your text. if so, you know that $savedata is not 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You have not passed or posted with name of `savedata`, from form submit button, i have used as below

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
```

instead of

```
$savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];
if ($savedata == 1){
```

Comment: I did this and now its showing: Couldn't open YOURDATAFILE.txt for writing!

Comment: do I need to have an empty .txt for it to open?

Comment: `fopen($file, "w+")` can you add and try this! make sure your `YOURDATAFILE.txt` file have necessary write permissions

Comment: it gave me the same result

Comment: Can you check the file path of the file.

Comment: of the php file? am I supposed to have an empty .txt file for this to open and write? sorry i am really confused.

Comment: no, txt file path! or you can delete the file and execute the script it create the file automatically. let me know your errorlog

Comment: honestly it would be great if I could get it to create a pdf but I am unsure of how to do that. I was trying to use tcpdf but could not figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a hidden form field setting savedata to 1 so that your if statement will complete:

```
<input name="savedata" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: A possible solution. Still probably better however, to modify the PHP as the above answers suggest rather than adding more data to travel across the wire. Anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

There's no `savedata` named field in the form. So i suggest that you use submit button's name to check if form is submitted. And `isset()` for checking value in php.

```
$savedata = $_REQUEST['value'];
if (isset($savedata)){
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no savedata element defined in the form.

I would also suggest you to be consistent in your code, get all elements with $_POST or $_REQUEST. Also, assign value to the name attribute of the form.